# jquery refreshing a div without using other files?

Tags: jquery

Right now, i know if i want to reload a div every xx seconds, i must place the div in a separate file, and use the first file to load then every xx seconds, so use code like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#chat_holder').load('file.page.php');

setInterval(function(){

        $('#chat_holder').load('file.page.php');

}, 10000);
});

</script>
```

..so this loads the content into this file.
Is there a way to only have one div and reload in every xx seconds in all in the same file?

Comment: This question is very unclear. The code you have should only load the contents of `file.page.php` into the `div#chat_holder` every 10 seconds. What are you asking?

Comment: ok, so basically, how can i reload a div every 10 seconds, and the div is in the same file as the jquery?

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#chat_holder").load("just-return-the-div-and-nothing-else.php")`?

Comment: Needing two files, I guess. @Archer

Comment: well, the file uses GET variables, and it does not seem to access them  when the file is within another...

Answer (score 0):

I think you `want to access a specific div` from `file.page.php` page:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#chat_holder').load('file.page.php #targetDivId');
     setInterval(function(){
        var loaded = $('#chat_holder').load('file.page.php #targetDivId');
        $('#chat_holder').html(loaded);
     }, 10000);
 });
```

This will load the targeted div into the `#chat_holder` div and this will do in every second

Comment: try with declaring var then replace the html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, but I doubt if it is 'good practice'. Look at this:

```
$("#chat_holder").load("thePageOfChatHolder.html #chatbox");
```

This will fetch the contents of `thePageOfChatHolder.html`, strip everything off except the chatbox and put that in `#chat_holder`.

**EDIT:**
Perhaps this solution will put the div 'in itself', like this:

```
<div id="chat_holder">
    <div id="chat_holder">
        <div id="chat_holder">
        ... and so on ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In that case, wrap `#chat_holder` in another div (in my example it has the ID `wrapper`) and do this:

```
$("#wrapper").load("thePageOfChatHolder.html #chat_holder");
```

Comment: Care to  share the reason for the downvote? I think this should work, so why downvote?

Comment: mmm that does not seem to be working, i have made the holder div, and loaded the posts (which are in a another div, and in the same file as the post holder) and changed thePageOfChatHolder.html to the file name...

Comment: The suggestion of putting a selector in the load call is correct, but to suggest using multiple elements with the same ID is definitely wrong and will break the page in many browsers.

Comment: Whut? Multiple elements with the same ID? I don't see that! @Archer